# PHP get x amount and insert rest

Tags: php

I am currently creating a script that need to take each 100 amount and add "1" to the row "days". I wanted to divide the amount by 100. So 100/100=1, but if i get a number with 150 it would become 150/100=1.5. These extra 50 in the 150 number needs to be put to the side (going into another row). And there cannot be any decimals in the row "days".

What is the smartest/simplest way to do this?

Some code:

```
$amount = 150;
$days = $amount/100; //no decimals here
//update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I found the solution to my question:

```
echo $amount%100;
```